# take runDate of cron job as an input to the script which is being run

Tags: linux

I have written a cronjob which runs on daily basis.

```
  #!/bin/sh
  Z=$(cat /home/saurabh/scripts/2017-09-15)
  echo "$Z"

  Y="File Content $Z ,Done"
  echo "$Y"
```

I have made an entry in crontab file to run this script on daily basis.

I want to take `2017-09-15` as a variable depending upon the date on which cron job is running. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the present date at the time of the cron run in your
specified format with `date -I`.  Right now, that matches the string
in your `Z`.

```
#! /bin/sh

# Optionally put into temp var.
dt=$(date -I)
Z=$(cat /home/saurabh/scripts/$(date -I))
# or: Z=$(cat /home/saurabh/scripts/$dt)
echo "$Z"
...
```